# Using powershell to turn a folder structure into an XML file

Tags: xml, powershell

I've been downloading a bunch of music the lately(yes yes, [perfectly legal](http://freemetalalbums.wordpress.com/))

Anyway, the random idea to turn the folderstructure into and XML file occured to me.
I don't know what I'd do with it, but I'd like to be able to do it.

So I turned to Windows Powershell. Turning any data into and XML file is done via:

```
$P = "command to get data"
$P | export-CliXML "where you want your XML file to be saved"
```

Still, I'm having trouble listing the folders. They're all saved on an external harddrive with the letter E, under the map "Music check later".

Can anybody help me here? I know that `Get-ChildItem -Recursive` is a part of it, but that's about as far as I'm getting here.

Comment: This would actually be a very useful thing to implement. I've thought of the same idea before, and it would be a simple and effective way to visualize the structure of a folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something as simple as:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'E:\Music check later' | Export-CliXML <outputfile>
```

Of course, the CliCML format outputs the XML as a Powershell object so you'll find a lot of extra information you may not need.

It might be worth your while using the output from GetChildItem to [generate your own XML schema](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/winpsh/payette3.mspx) based on your needs.

Comment: Keep in mind that Export-CliXml exports 2 levels deep by default and can be increased using the -depth parameter.

Comment: Depth Parameter you say. I'll look into it. Hopefully there's a "full depth" option.

Answer (score 1):

With PowerShell CTP3 you can use the ConvertTo-XML cmdlet. You'll need to know how deep your folder structure is in advance. By default the cmdlet convert the first level only. You can increase it with using the -Depth parameter.